# How can I only show ToolTip on specific words in a Label?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, mxml, flex-spark

> Take this **text** for **example**.

I would like to be able to display something like the text above, and let the user mouse over "text" and "example" to get two different `ToolTip` messages (lets say, "text: noun...definition: ...", and "example: noun...definition" respectively).

In this case, the text is static, so one option would be to put 4 different labels next to each other and style them differently. This might work in most cases, but i also need the text to word-wrap which wouldn't work with individual labels.

Can anyone recommend a solution for this?

Comment: Can you add an event listener for `MouseOver` or `MouseMove` events, use it to toggle the tooltip on and off, and also use it to check where the cursor is over the label and dynamically set the tooltip's text at runtime?

Comment: That is an option, but I'm not quite sure how to determine what text is being hovered over via the x/y coordinates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't seem to get much love in our community, but you'll want to look at the TLF Engine. Specifically a TextFlow which has said "primitive" events (eg mouse__, roll__) for links. Style the link appropriately, and in theory you should be close to being done. Since this isn't a Flex-SDK baked-in component, it won't handle the toolTip for you, but it's easy enough to replicate. Create a new ToolTip manually - and add it to the PopUpManager.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS02f7d8d4857b1677-165a04e1126951a2d98-7ffc.html